# Glut Error on Mac with Haskell Program

Tags: macos, haskell, glut

I am trying to run a Haskell program which has to use GLUT (to draw shapes) but I get this error message :

`*** Exception: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutSetOption)`

My program works and GLUT lauches when I run it on Linux

So I only get this problem from my Mac..

Comment: Is there a particular value you're sending to `glutSetOption` when the error occurs?

Comment: I believe this is caused because the Haskell GLUT library is linked against GLUT rather than freeGLUT (only the latter has `glutSetOption`). But I haven't figured out how to link against freeGLUT on a Mac...

Answer (score 0):

As user2141650 suggested in a comment, this seems to be caused by a discrepancy between the default macOS GLUT and freeGLUT. Since version 2.7.0.12, [Haskell GLUT automatically picks freeGLUT](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/GLUT/pull/25) if it's installed. Here's how I managed to install freeGLUT:

- Install XQuartz:

  - `brew cask install xquartz` or
  - install the `.dmg` from [xquartz.org](https://www.xquartz.org/).
- `brew install freeglut`

After I installed XQuartz and freeGLUT with `brew`, my program still couldn't open the display. As suggested in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/y6e59/xquartz_and_apparently_incorrectly_set_display/), I did the following:

- `launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist`
- restarted my computer

Maybe the `launchctl` command would have been enough, or maybe restarting the computer would have done it, or maybe all that isn't necessary if you install XQuarts using the `.dmg` file. I don't know. Good luck!